# How to check version of ssh-keygen?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, help-files, ssh-keygen

What command can be used in Linux to display the version of ssh-keygen? Its man page doesn't tell the version, oddly, nor does it mention any option to do it (e.g. `-v` or `--version`). Of no use is `apt-cache` either, as it shows the version of the whole containing package (ssh).

Comment: Try `-V` for version (upper case).

Comment: Nope. `option requires an argument -- V`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ssh-keygen does not have its own version separate from the whole containing package (which corresponds to the version of the OpenSSH release that was packaged).

So if `dpkg -l openssh\*` says it's "8.4", then /usr/bin/ssh-keygen is also version 8.4.

Only some OpenSSH tools have an option to display the version, in particular `ssh` does, so if you run `ssh -V` (or `/usr/bin/ssh -V` just to be sure) and it says 8.4p1, then all other `ssh-*` tools included in the same package also have version 8.4p1.

---

The GitLab article says "SSH version 6.5 or later" – I'm pretty sure it means OpenSSH 6.5 or later, as there is no SSH protocol version 6.5 (protocol SSHv2 is still current).

OpenSSH 6.5 did not *use* MD5, but rather had the *ability* to use it (much like older TLS clients had the ability to speak SSLv3) – as far as I understand, only if connecting to an outdated server which required RSA-MD5, not all the time. Also, this only affected server-client communication but not key generation (SSH keys don't have long-term signatures in them at all).

Comment: It says `1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.1`. What do then the versions mentioned [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html) refer to? I saw the initial `1` and assumed it was some unrelated version number and that indeed ssh-keygen was versioned separately. But maybe it's the `8.9` after the `1:`?

Comment: `8.9p1` is the actual upstream version; `1:` is what Debian calls an "epoch", I believe (had to be used to force apt to treat a downgrade as an upgrade, a long time ago). `-3ubuntu0.1` are various Debian-level adjustments (i.e. repackaging of the same 8.9p1) as well as Ubuntu-level adjustments on top of that.

Comment: When [the GitLab page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html) says "SSH version 6.5 or later. Earlier versions used an MD5 signature, which is not secure", they're most likely referring to *OpenSSH* version 6.5 (older OpenSSH versions used to display MD5 fingerprints – but they never made MD5-based signatures, so I don't know why the page is saying "signatures"). This only affects the `ECDSA key fingerprint is ...` message and doesn't directly influence the quality of generated keys.

Comment: I looked into this a bit more and apparently yes, there _used to be_ rsa+md5 usage in SSH which was removed in OpenSSH 6.5 – but that's not key generation; it's in the communication between client and server, so it is not so much "used" as "had the ability to use, when connecting to a similarly outdated server".